# How to create partial function from runtime value in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create partial function from runtime value and combine partial functions after that like this:

```
class Test(val function: PartialFunction[Int, Boolean]) {
  def add(v: Int): Test = {
    new Test(function.orElse{case v => true})
  }
  def contains(v: Int) = function.isDefinedAt(v)
}

val test: Test = new Test({case 1 => true})
val test2 = test.add(2)
println(test2.contains(1))
println(test2.contains(2))
println(test2.contains(3))
```

This code prints

```
true
true
true
```

But the last line should be false.
Why is this so? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{ case v => true }` is always a match. You want to test the value of `v`:

```
  new Test(function.orElse{case `v` => true})
```

Comment: Can you, please, provide more info about cases when `isDefinedAt` can return true even if the function will fail?

Comment: I have re-checked the documentation and I was wrong about this. `isDefinedAt` does accurately  indicate whether a value is handled by the partial function or not. So your code is good to go, and apologies for confusing things.